# Linux shell script regex match

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a text file.
I want to get lines starting with specific format.
I just want to get lines that have x/x/x format. x is a number.
But this regex is not working. It is always giving no match :

```
while read line           
do           
    regex="\d+\/\d+\/\d+"
    if [[ ${line} =~  ${regex} ]]; then 

        echo ${line}

    else

        echo "no match : ${line}"

    fi    
done <${textFileName}
```

File is :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use bash if you can use a better tool:

```
grep -E '^[[:digit:]]+/[[:digit:]]+/[[:digit:]]+' "${textFileName}"
```

But if you have to use bash:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  if [[ "$line}" =~ ^[[:digit:]]+/[[:digit:]]+/[[:digit:]]+ ]]; then
     echo -- "$line"
  else
    echo "no match: $line"
  fi
done < "$textFileName"
```

`\d` is not valid `regex(3)`.

Comment: Hi i applied your code. But didnt work.     while IFS= read -r line
    do
  
        if [[ "${line}" =~ '[[:digit:]]+/[[:digit:]]+/[[:digit:]]+' ]]; then
            echo -- "X:$line"
        else
            echo "no match: $line"
        fi
    done < "$textFileName"

Comment: Don't quote the regex